# problem with 3x3 3d rotation matrices logic - concatenation doesn't work as expected

Tags: math, 3d, matrix, geometry, rotation

In basic words I need a simple and fast algorithm to find the solution X from C * X = M where all variable are matrices. More explanations below.

I'm trying to compute one specific matrix but it doesn't really work as expected:

```
Vz - negative Z-axis vector (or any other)
Vg - current gravity vector
Vc - zero reference vector (for gravity calibration)

M0 - current rotation matrix
C0 - reference rotation matrix
X0 - unknown rotation matrix to find
*t - transposed versions of above matrices

Upong runtime only Vg, M and C are known.

Rules:

1) Vz == Vg * M0
2) Vg == Vz * Mt
3) Vz == Vc * C0
4) Vc == Vz * Ct
5) Vz == Vx * X0
6) Vx == Vz * Xt
7) Vx == Vg * C0
8) M0 == C0 * X0 (wrong!!! see update notes below)
...
?) X0 = ?
```

I tried to use formula like that:

```
X0 = M0 * Ct
```

But the resulting matrix does not satifsy the rules (5) and (6) as expected.

Any ideas what's wrong here?

**UPDATE:**

The formula I tried (X0 = M0 * Ct) is correct.
The question was incorrect as (8) is actually M0 = X0 * C0.

The problem why I thought it doesn't work was because I tried to compute Vx = Vg * C0 - but actually neither Vx = Vg * C0 nor Vg = Vx * Ct are correct.

Thus I'm moving to the next task - that is better to describe as a new question :-)

Comment: Could you please explain in plain words what you are trying to achieve? Just a note: rules 2, 4 and 6 are redundant, they hold iff 1, 3, and 5 holds, resp.

Answer (score 0):

If `M0 = C0 * X0` (rule 8), then `X0 = Ct * M0` (your formula `X0 = M0 * Ct` is wrong).

If this `X0` does not also satisfy the other rules, then your set of rules doesn't have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know two things:

- For rotations, transposes are inverses
- Matrix multiplication does not commute.

We know:

```
  M0 = C0 * X0  (8)
```

and these are rotations. So:

```
inverse (C0) = Ct
```

Pre-multiply (8) by Ct:

```
Ct * M0 = Ct * C0 * X0
        = X0
```

And hence we have X0.

Comment: well this works as it should - correctly. The only thing - it doesn't give the right results anyway - what means that the calibration matrix C is computed in a wrong way.